# Best way to search through every value of a hashmap containing lists as the values?

Tags: java, list, search, hashmap

I have a hashmap defined as:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

The map is being used for a search feature, where the key is the name, and the value is a list of all the keywords pertaining to that name. Keywords are not necessarily unique to each name.

What is the fastest way to search through all the keywords stored in the lists?

Answer (score 0):

Given the structure you use, there's no fastest way here. You have only one way - given a key, get the List of keywords for that key. Then loop through that List of keywords.

And if you want to search through all keywords (that are present in all Lists of keywords), regardless of their keys, then I suggest you maintain also a HashSet of all the keywords present.

Comment: Surely that one way is also the fastest way?

Comment: @IsmailBadawi If you understand OP's problem in details, and if you think so, then so be it.

Comment: I just mean that if there is only one way, then that way is the fastest way by default.

Comment: @peter.petrov is there a better structure I can use for this?

Comment: @mguida It is not clear what your original problem is. If you explain your problem in details, people will be able to suggest the best way for solving it.

Comment: @peter.petrov i need a search that uses keywords to find the correct item. So if I have Computer as the item, keywords might be laptop, CPU, etc. When the user types CPU, it should pull up Computer as a possible result

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention whether your lists are sorted or whether each list must allow duplicate values.

If the Lists can be sorted by value, then you can use [Collections.binarySearch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch-java.util.List-T-).  Note that the concrete type of your Lists should be an implementation that supports random access--e.g., ArrayList instead of LinkedList.

If the Lists are unsorted and each list should only contain one copy of each value, I'd suggest changing the Lists to Sets (e.g., HashSet or TreeSet).

If the Lists must be sorted by insertion order or each list must be allowed to store the same value multiple times, you can use an auxiliary Set for fast lookup.